# How to use map/reduce on Python Ordered dictionary

Tags: python, lambda, mapreduce

I have a nested python dictionary like this :

```
my_dictionary = {"Ab" : {'name': 'usa', 'boolean': 'YES'},
"Ac" : {'name': 'usa', 'boolean': 'NO'},
"Ad": {'name': 'UK', 'boolean': 'NO'},
"Ae": {'name': 'UK', 'boolean': 'NO'}}
```

I created an ordered dictionary from the above dictionary like this :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dictionary.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]['name']))
print sorted_dict
```

This gives:

```
OrderedDict([("Ab", {'name': 'usa', 'boolean': 'YES'}),
("Ac", {'name': 'usa', 'boolean': 'NO'}),
("Ad", {'name': 'UK', 'boolean': 'NO'}),
("Ae", {'name': 'UK', 'boolean': 'NO'})])
```

I need to add a new column ('result') to the ordered dictionary. The logic for creating the new column is as follows:

Collect all rows which have the same 'name' : here 'usa' and 'UK'. Then apply reduce method based on 'boolean' column. The function should be binary 'OR' (||).

I tried to apply reduce like this :

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x['boolean'] or y['boolean']
```

but got stuck in choosing all the rows with same 'name'.

So the final Ordered dictionary will look like :

```
OrderedDict([("Ab", {'name': 'usa', 'boolean': 'YES', 'result': 'YES'}),
("Ac", {'name': 'usa', 'boolean': 'NO', 'result': 'YES'}),
("Ad", {'name': 'UK', 'boolean': 'NO', 'result': 'NO'}),
("Ae", {'name': 'UK', 'boolean': 'NO', 'result': 'NO'})])
```

Comment: What about using dataframes from the pandas package?

Comment: @Elmex80s : I was thinking about that as well. But, Can it be integrated into a pure python codebase. I had used pandas only on notebooks not in a full fledged project

Comment: don't use `sorted` as your variable name, it shadows the built-in `sorted` method, and could cause problems for you.

Comment: @InbarRose : Thanks. Edited now

Comment: @Elmex80s :  "YES" . Edited now :-) Could you please upvote the question for more visibility :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a method that seems to work with the data you provided, but I am not sure how this has to do with reduce.

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict

d = OrderedDict([("Ab", {'name': 'usa', 'boolean': 'YES'}),
                 ("Ac", {'name': 'usa', 'boolean': 'NO'}),
                 ("Ad", {'name': 'UK', 'boolean': 'NO'}),
                 ("Ae", {'name': 'UK', 'boolean': 'NO'})])


def add_result(d, ikey='name', check='boolean', tt='YES', ff='NO'):
    # hold results per ikey
    ikey_results = defaultdict(lambda: ff)
    # first pass to get results
    for v in d.values():
        if v[check] == tt:
            ikey_results[v[ikey]] = tt
    # second pass to embedd results
    for v in d.values():
        v['result'] = ikey_results[v[ikey]]
    return d

print add_result(d)
```

Yields

```
OrderedDict([('Ab', {'boolean': 'YES', 'name': 'usa', 'result': 'YES'}),
             ('Ac', {'boolean': 'NO', 'name': 'usa', 'result': 'YES'}), 
             ('Ad', {'boolean': 'NO', 'name': 'UK', 'result': 'NO'}), 
             ('Ae', {'boolean': 'NO', 'name': 'UK', 'result': 'NO'})])
```

Comment: This answer is definitely right . Checking others as well

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you a little bit:

1. the ordered dictionary you introduce doesn't matter much here. You can omit it and introduce it when you are done with your logic
2. I would transform `"Yes"` to `True` and `"No"` to `False` at the very first beginning. Make life easy, not complicated
3. You can do without `lambda` and `reduce`. Python has list comprehension together with the `any` statement. `any` applies the Boolean `or` operator to a list of Boolean values.

Comment: I like your second point. For the first point : I have 10000's of columns like this . This is the simplest version. I thought once I sort it, I should be able to grab the rows with the same values in "name" column.

Comment: @user3683555 thank you, but the first and third point might be valuable as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get it well. But I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import groupby


def reduceByKey(func, iterable): 
    return map(              
      lambda l: (l[0], reduce(func, map(lambda p: p[1], l[1]))),
      groupby(sorted(iterable, key=lambda p: p[0]), lambda p: p[0])
    )

reduceByKey(
  # Are you sure you want to do ("YES" or "NO") not (True or False) ?
  lambda x, y: x or y
  map(lambda d: yourDict[d]["name"], yourDict[d]["boolean"], yourDict)
)
```

`yourDict` here is your original dictionary

Answer (score 1):

This

```
from pprint import pprint

my_dictionary = {"Ab": {'name': 'usa', 'boolean': True},
                 "Ac": {'name': 'usa', 'boolean': False},
                 "Ad": {'name': 'UK', 'boolean': False},
                 "Ae": {'name': 'UK', 'boolean': False}}

sub_result = dict()

for x in my_dictionary.values():
    country_name = x['name']
    sub_result[country_name ] = sub_result.get(country_name , False) or x['boolean']


new_dictionary = {k: dict(v.items() + [('result', sub_result[v['name']])]) for k, v in my_dictionary.items()}


pprint(new_dictionary)
```

No ordered dictionary needed.

Comment: Yes, but you are destroying the old object, and creating a new one. The OP desired in-place IMHO.

Comment: @InbarRose In that case remove the dictionary comprehension and replace it by a for loop.